# Excel: How to check/format column for duplicates IF a specific cell equals certain text? VBA not an option

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a worksheet that needs to check/format a range of cells for duplicates ONLY IF a specific cell contains certain text.

I have attempted several different formulas in the Conditional Formatting but haven't found one that will do what I need. VBA is not an option because of security restrictions.

Example:

If Cell B34 = "Passive" then highlight duplicate values red in the cell range B37:B66.
If Cell B34 <> "Passive" then do not check for duplicates

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting

Comment: @ScottCraner: I attempted to use Conditional Formatting but the "Duplicate Values" option would not allow me to use a restrictive formula and the "Formula" option would not allow me to format only duplicates after checking a B34="Passive"

Comment: Conditional formatting with something like: `AND(B$34="Passive", COUNTIF(B$37:B$66,B37)` should do the trick

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad based on an earlier answer/comment by Mr. Craner, using match is faster than COUNTIF

Comment: @Robert, are you finding `Passive` in the Column `as duplicate` or any other even?